# About the collision map of PR2

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, collision, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I have some problems when I try to get the collision map of PR2. The error is that "Client [/rviz_collision_tutorial_1] wants topic /tilt_scan_cloud_filtered to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/PointCloud/d8e9c3f5afbdd8a130fd1d2763945fca], but our version has [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181]. Dropping connection." My ROS is fuerte. Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140536/about-the-collision-map-of-pr2/) by [hannuaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/13401/hannuaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hannuaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/13401/hannuaa/) on 2014-03-16**:
i refer to the tutorials in "http://wiki.ros.org/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials/Making collision maps from self-filtered tilting laser data" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the text from the tutorial page you are referring to:

**If using an OpenNI device that outputs only PointCloud2, you should use a node from collider or octomap_server instead.**

This is your problem and solution.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0